# C# Linq multiple queries in a single one

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I'm new in Linq and I'm trying to optimize some queries and I don't have any idea if it is possible for this queries:

```
var cSRez = (from l in MyTable
                 where l.Name == "dcc" && l.Service == "Main"
                 orderby l.Time descending
                 select l.Value).FirstOrDefault();
var cDRez = (from l in MyTable
                 where l.Name == "dcc" && l.Service == "DB"
                 orderby l.Time descending
                 select l.Value).FirstOrDefault();
var dSRez = (from l in MyTable
                 where l.Name == "ddc" && l.Service == "Main"
                 orderby l.Time descending
                 select (long?)l.Value).FirstOrDefault();
var dDRez = (from l in MyTable
                 where l.Name == "ddc" && l.Service == "DB"
                 orderby l.Time descending
                 select (long?)l.Value).FirstOrDefault();
var mSRez = (from l in MyTable
                  where l.Name == "mc" && l.Service == "Main"
                  orderby l.Time descending
                  select l.Value).FirstOrDefault();
var mDRez = (from l in MyTable
                  where l.Name == "mc" && l.Service == "DB"
                  orderby l.Time descending
                  select l.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

to become a single one. 
I was thinking about `row_number() over(partition by...` (SQL) but I don't think this is the best idea for doing this.

It is possible to collapse this six separate queries into a single one?

Comment: Put that inside of a method and call it?

Comment: @Sach How would that make them one query?

Comment: @maccettura There would also need to use some type of group by because of the `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve by combining it into one query? you are selecting only 1 result each time, do you want to have all the results in one variable?

Comment: @juharr it wouldn't. But the query does the same thing over and over again so just calling a method is better. I should not have been lazy and taken the time to explain that.

Comment: @ZivWeissman I'm having some issues with the performance so I was thinking that by making all of them as a single one will solve it

Comment: If it is only a performance issue this is mainly because you order by desc each time you perform query. It is better to do this only once. Perhaps if you don't have many results with Service "Main" or "DB" i'd start by getting all the results that matches Service = "Main" || "DB" order by whatever (don't forget .ToList()), then get the FirstOrDefault with your combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to group on the Name and Service and then filter on the specific pairs you want then select the Name and Service and the Value from the First match.  Note that any pairs that do not exist will not be represented in the results and you'd have to handle that when you pull the values out.

```
var results = (from l in MyTable
              group l by new {l.Name, l.Service} into grp
              where (grp.Key.Name == "dcc" && grp.Key.Service == "Main")
                  || (grp.Key.Name == "dcc" && grp.Key.Service == "DB")
                  || ....
              select new
              {
                  grp.Key,
                  Value = grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.Time).Select(x => x.Value).First()
              }).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Then to pull out the results

```
results.TryGetValue(new { Name = "dcc", Service = "Main" }, out var cSRez);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how EF would translate this query to SQL, but I would try this approach:

```
var rawData = MyTable
    .Where(l => (l.Name=="dcc" || l.Name=="ddc" || l.Name=="mc") && (l.Service=="Main" || l.Service=="Db"))
    .GroupBy(l => new { l.Name, l.Service })
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(l => l.Time).First())
    .ToList();
```

This should yield up to six rows of interest to your program. Now you can retrieve each row by specifying the specific combination of `Name` and `Service`:

```
var cSRez = rawData.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == "dcc" && l.Service == "Main");
var cDRez = rawData.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == "dcc" && l.Service == "DB");
var dSRez = rawData.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == "ddc" && l.Service == "Main");
var dDRez = rawData.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == "ddc" && l.Service == "DB");
var mSRez = rawData.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == "mc" && l.Service == "Main");
var mDRez = rawData.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == "mc" && l.Service == "DB");
```

Note that the six queries on `rawData` are performed in memory on a list of fixed size of up to six items, so they are not costing you additional round-trips to RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will execute faster as a single query or not, as the query is somewhat complex, so I think it may depend on server side query time versus query setup and data transmission time.

You can convert into a single query that gathers all the answers at once, and then break that answer up for each variable.

This first answer takes the result and converts into a double nested `Dictionary` for the values and then pulls the variables out of the `Dictionary`:

```
var ansd = (from l in MyTable
            where new[] { "dcc", "ddc", "mc" }.Contains(l.Name) && new[] { "Main", "DB" }.Contains(l.Service)
            group l by new { l.Name, l.Service } into ag
            select new {
                ag.Key.Name,
                ag.Key.Service,
                Value = ag.OrderByDescending(l => l.Time).First().Value
            })
            .GroupBy(nsv => nsv.Name)
            .ToDictionary(nsvg => nsvg.Key, nsvg => nsvg.ToDictionary(nsv => nsv.Service, arv => arv.Value));

long? cSRez = null, cDRez = null, dSRez = null, dDRez = null, mSRez = null, mDRez = null;
if (ansd.TryGetValue("dcc", out var td)) td.TryGetValue("Main", out cSRez);
if (ansd.TryGetValue("dcc", out td)) td.TryGetValue("DB", out cDRez);
if (ansd.TryGetValue("ddc", out td)) td.TryGetValue("Main", out dSRez);
if (ansd.TryGetValue("ddc", out td)) td.TryGetValue("DB", out dDRez);
if (ansd.TryGetValue("mc", out td)) td.TryGetValue("Main", out mSRez);
if (ansd.TryGetValue("mc", out td)) td.TryGetValue("DB", out mDRez);
```

Given that there are only six answers, creating `Dictionary`s for them may be overkill. Instead, you can just (sequentially) find the matching answers:

```
var ansl = (from l in MyTable
            where new[] { "dcc", "ddc", "mc" }.Contains(l.Name) && new[] { "Main", "DB" }.Contains(l.Service)
            group l by new { l.Name, l.Service } into ag
            select new {
                ag.Key.Name,
                ag.Key.Service,
                Value = ag.OrderByDescending(l => l.Time).First().Value
            })
            .ToList();

var cSRez = ansl.FirstOrDefault(ansv => ansv.Name == "dcc" && ansv.Service == "Main");
var cDRez = ansl.FirstOrDefault(ansv => ansv.Name == "dcc" && ansv.Service == "DB");
var dSRez = ansl.FirstOrDefault(ansv => ansv.Name == "ddc" && ansv.Service == "Main");
var dDRez = ansl.FirstOrDefault(ansv => ansv.Name == "ddc" && ansv.Service == "DB");
var mSRez = ansl.FirstOrDefault(ansv => ansv.Name == "mc" && ansv.Service == "Main");
var mDRez = ansl.FirstOrDefault(ansv => ansv.Name == "mc" && ansv.Service == "DB");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your query in a private method that takes an Exression and returns Value and call it for each variable (e.g. cDRez, cSRez etc) simply passing different expressions.

```
private Value GetValue(Expression<Func<MyTable, bool>> filter) {
    return MyTable.Where(filter).OrderByDescending(o => o.Time).Select(s => s.Value).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Call it like with different filters for each variable:

```
var cSRez = GetValue(l => l.Name == "dcc" && l.Service == "Main");
var cDRez = GetValue(l => l.Name == "dcc" && l.Service == "DB");
var dSRez = GetValue(l => l.Name == "ddc" && l.Service == "Main");
var dDRez = GetValue(l => l.Name == "ddc" && l.Service == "DB");
var mSRez = GetValue(l => l.Name == "mc" && l.Service == "Main");
var mDRez = GetValue(l => l.Name == "mc" && l.Service == "DB");
```

Comment: That doesn't make it one query.  That just dries out the existing code which I don't think is what the OP was asking for.